# Calibrating Dual Monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, calibration

I have attached an additional monitor with my laptop. The issue is, the calibration and the LCD quality of both monitors are different. What is the best way to calibrate them? My eyes are becoming painful on Switching between

Answer (score 0):

If you were a graphics professional you may want to calibrate your monitor using a [Spyder](http://www.datacolor.eu/en/products/monitor-calibration/spyder3elite/index.html), so that what you see on the screen looks as close as possible to how it should on other calibrated monitors, and how it would look like in print.

You can also calibrate your monitor using software tools (like the wizard in Windows Media Centre), but you have not mentioned which operating system you use.  There is a Colour Calibration tool in the Windows Control Panel and sometimes there is one in graphics card software.

However, it sounds like you just have two screens of different types, and you cannot expect them to have the same qualities.  Some have different characteristics to others, and there are different LCD technologies (TN, PVA, IPS, LED backlighting, etc).

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you running?

If you use Windows 7, it has a monitor calibrating tool built in. Type 'Calibrate' in the start menu search box, and open the link 'Calibrate Display Color'. This will open the calibration window (seen below). Just follow the instructions through on one screen to calibrate it, then when you're finished, move the window to the other screen and do the same thing.

[image]

You should then have two properly calibrated monitors!